# Magento on shared hosting and ' Full Page Cache'

Tags: full-page-cache

If Magento is hosted on a shared server and 'PageCache powered by Varnish' is out of the question, would anyone recommend some of the other Magento page cache plugins like:

Booster: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/performance-booster.html

Zoom: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zoom-full-page-cache-1742.html

Nitrogento: http://www.nitrogento.com/

Brim: http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/full-page-cache-magento.html

[update]

Lesti: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesti-fpc-4534.html
(free)

Are they all 'just not worth it'?, is there one that stands out from a bad bunch?

Cheers,

Les

Comment: This plugin also seems popular http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/full-page-cache-magento.html

Comment: If you have / your client has enough traffic & business to justify a CE FPC module, then your Magento instance should not be on shared hosting.

Answer (score 2):

We have used Lightspeed (http://www.tinybrick.com/improve-magentos-slow-performance.html) in quite a few projects and also consider using Zoom Full Page Cache as it seems a free viable option. The speed improvement is very good, all full page cache modules work by caching the whole html page (usually for cms pages, products and categories). Even if the cache is based on files the speed boost is visible. The only case where I would not consider these modules is if you are having most of your traffic coming from logged in users, as most of the community cache modules will not cache much. If this is the case, the best option is the built-in Full Page Cache on Magento Enterprise.

Comment: Lightspeed works very well and was worth the money spent.

Comment: Not affiliated with the company in any way, TinyBrick changed their name to Open Commerce and the name of their cache from Lightspeed to Warp. This is done to keep the above content relevant.

Answer (score 1):

We've used Brim full page cache on several shops and it works pretty good, the company also provides great support.
http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/full-page-cache-magento.html

Answer (score 1):

we have tested both Zoom and Brim FPC.

- Zoom is opensource and was developed by Ezapps. Sadly there was no community and the code is as it is since version 1. It actually performed very very fast. But there is no support. And ou will run into problems when you implement (non default) themes or extensions that dont collaborate with Zoom.
- Brim FPC. We are very happy with it. Although the "only 6 months" support is something I have never really understood. It is easily configurable, quite fast en I must say support by Brian is more than you could wish for. The only thing really missing is a cachewarmer (so the page is fast from minute 1)
- Nitrogento we tested. (It didnt work with our extensions, but can be our fault)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, so it's looks like Brim FPC isn't a bad choice?

Comment: We have heard good things about Brim.

Comment: Me too. Support and having the idea that people actually like to help and improve is key

Comment: OK, I'm going to purchase Brim FPC today and test out.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the following (should be) mega fast

Install REDIS cache manager + Lesti FPC

Lesti: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesti-fpc-4534.html (free)

For speed ........ combine REDIS for use with 
cache:https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis
session: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession
fpc: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesti-fpc-4534.html

All in memory and very fast. 512Mb to 1GB of RAM is enough (for regular stores)

Answer (score 0):

FPC does not help unless non-cached page loads are under 3s, it just hides the problem, it does not solve it. The problem is for <3s non-cached you need good hosting architecture and most are not willing to pay for that as it should be 0.5-1% of revenue. In the end non-cached not matchting FPC affects Google ranking and increases cart abandonment, the simple point is FPC increases the number of visitors a server can handle, it does not directly increase performance. Give it a few months, you will see what we mean with Google and paying visitors.

Answer (score 0):

It will belong to your traffic and server hardware, but in the case your hardware is well enough with RAM >= 512 MB and CPU 2 cores. You can use the combination of these: Lesti + Redis + APC. They are all free and at least it can help your magento site load less than 1 second